# How to implement a background queue in android?

Tags: android

I want to implement a background queue. It works as: when user click a button, add a task (this task need time to be done) to the queue, queue should run on the background thread. If user click button again, add another task in the queue. The background thread runs the tasks in the queue one by one until the queue is empty. I want it only be 1 background thread working on the task. What kind of android feature I can use? or is there any example?

Comment: Create a List of Work that needs handling, Start an AsyncTask once the User Clicks an Element, keep Track of that Task to be aware if it has finished working. If the user clicks a new item, add it to queue. if Async has finished, start a new one.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: you can use an intent service to queue tasks - it uses a single worker  thread. docs - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out using `AsyncTask` with a `SingleThreadExecuter`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably at least a few ways to solve that problem. You can try to use low-level implementations with Executors and so on, but I'd give an [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library by Evernote a try.

Comment: I wouldn't call using AsyncTasks and an executor "low-level".   That's just what the platform provides for such tasks. I have nothing anything against helpful libraries but AsyncTasks are fairly simple to implement.

Comment: You're right, but using Executors may be not so obvious for everyone and requires some knowledge about concurrency, so I wouldn't say that it's so easy. Moreover, AsyncTask has some stability issues, no error handling and I'd avoid using it. Approach suggested by you requires writing similar tool I linked above from the scratch and "re-inventing the wheel". If you want to use things from SDK, I'd suggest using Job Scheduler, but it's available only in the latest Android API.

Comment: Reinvent the wheel? You create a class that extends AsyncTask to perform your background logic.  Call Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor () to create a single-thread executor and you hand it to each AsyncTask when you execute it.  There's not a lot to it.